# Animate fixed element to the center of the viewport

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have an element that is `position: fixed;` in the upper right corner of the page.
I want it to "grow and move" to the center of the screen when clicked.

The best solution I'm aware of to position something in the dead center of the page is

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Everything works great if I have the element initially positioned with `top` and `left` properties, but there is a nasty jump in the animation if the element is initially positioned with `right` instead of `left`.

```js
const myFunc = function() {
  let f = document.getElementById('element')

  if (f.className.includes('bar')) {
    f.className = 'foo'
  } else {
    f.className = 'foo bar'
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.foo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: 0.5s all;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="foo" id="element" onclick="myFunc()">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLpvRy)

How do I get rid of the initial jump in the animation to the horizontal center? (i.e. I want the reverse of the "shrinking back to top right", here everything works fine).

Comment: when using `right`, you can use `top: 50%;
right: 50%;
transform: translate(50%, -50%);`?

Comment: see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LoVzrR

Comment: Son of a &§***, I swear I tried every variation of that ;-) Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the right to left on the `foo` state.
This also implies you change the translate property to : `translate(50%,-50%);` as the tanslateX value should be from left to right to center the element :

```js
const myFunc = function () {
  let f = document.getElementById('element')

  if(f.className.includes('bar')) {
    f.className = 'foo'
  }
  else {
    f.className = 'foo bar'
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.foo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  transition: 0.5s all;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="foo" id="element" onclick="myFunc()">
  </div>
</div>
```

On a side note, if you know the size of your element in both states you could make the transition only on the top and right properties using `calc()` like this :

```js
const myFunc = function() {
  let f = document.getElementById('element')

  if (f.className.includes('bar')) {
    f.className = 'foo'
  } else {
    f.className = 'foo bar'
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.foo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(50% - 250px);
  right: calc(50% - 250px);
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="foo" id="element" onclick="myFunc()">
  </div>
</div>
```

This changes the animation trajectory and prevents the element from beeing animated in one direction with top/right and in the ohter at the same time by the `transform` property.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit, this gave me some trouble at first, but with some perseverance I was able to get you there lol

This is because you're not giving the CSS transition a starting point from which to associate the `right` property positioning. You've switched from giving the element a `right` property of `20px` to a `left` property of `50%`. For the effect you want, you need to give it a starting `right` position of `20px` and an *ending* `right` position of `50%` for `.bar` (getting rid of the `left: 50%;`).

Now, after you fix the above mentioned issue, you'll need to address the `.bar` class `transform` method by making it `transform: translate(50%, -50%);` This is because we've switched to using `right` x-axis positioning, so we need it to go `50%` from the right, rather than `-50%` (which would make the element go off-screen `-50%` of the space from the dead center of the parent).

[Here is your new live demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwOpBP). I hope this makes sense :) CSS logically requires all transitions to have a starting point and a valid, cohabitated ending point. Some browsers make the assumption for you, but they should never do that because that will stymie development cross-platform.

Comment: @TommyF dis you check my answer?